Each array should contain unique element using Facet in MongoDB
Here I'm adding the Mongo playground URL how my schema structure look like
Now I want 3 unique array elements which are mostPurchased, latestRewards and suggestedRewards.
So I'm trying to achieve by using $facet
{
    $facet: {
      mostPurchased: [
        {
          $sort: {
            buyerCount: -1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 15
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            doc: {
              $first: "$$ROOT"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$doc"
          }
        }
      ],
      latestRewards: [
        {
          $sort: {
            created: -1
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            doc: {
              $first: "$$ROOT"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$doc"
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 15
        }
      ],
      suggestedRewards: [
        {
          $match: {
            points: {
              $lt: 300
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            doc: {
              $first: "$$ROOT"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$doc"
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 15
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      mostPurchased: 1,
      latestRewards: 1,
      suggestedRewards: 1
    }
  }

But this one producing the duplicate element on each array.
Note: All the stage aggregations should be perform before the projection so that it each array would contain 15 elements. for reference I added 8 elements on mongo playground.
Let me know where I'm going wrong

why are you also grouping by id since id is already unique it is already grouped

I want to replace existing root once it got pushed to respective array.

In your playground example each array member has a unique _id value, what is being duplicated?

My intention is to any element shouldn't be repeat across the 3 array. If any element present in one array and sme element shouldn't be appear another array

There is not enough data in your sample dataset to illustrate top 15 for each groups, so this example uses top 2 to illustrate.
The idea is to assign to each group only once. Here, we assume the priority would be:

mostPurchased
latestRewards
suggestedRewards

So if a document matched all groups, it would be assigned to mostPurchased group. If a document matched only group 2 and 3, it would be assigned to group 2. This behaviour is configurable and will be explained in later code.
The aggregation pipeline would be like below:

your previous $project and other stages
$setWindowFields to compute mostPurchasedRank with $rank
$setWindowFields to compute latestRewardsRank with $rank
$set a field grouping with $switch. Here is the part where we configure the priority. Based on the calculated rankings in step 2 and 3, we  assign documents into different groups.
$setWindowFields to compute inGroupRanking with $rank. This helps to avoid we are having too many documents in a group(thus breaching MongoDB 16MB document size limit in later stage)
$match to select inGroupRanking <= 2(i.e. document number per group, would be 15 in your original case)
7.(optional) $group by grouping to push all docs inside.

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      validity: "$validity",
      name: "$name.en",
      points: "$points",
      _id: "$_id",
      description: "$description.en",
      image: "$image",
      colorCode: "$colorCode",
      backgroundColorCode: {
        $ifNull: [
          "$backgroundColorCode",
          "#FF0000"
        ]
      },
      categoryId: {
        _id: "$categoryId._id",
        name: "$categoryId.name"
      },
      created: "$created",
      totalPoints: "$totalPoints",
      rewardType: "CUSTOM_REWARD",
      sponsorName: "$sponsorName",
      sponsorNameColor: {
        $ifNull: [
          "$sponsorNameColor",
          "#808080"
        ]
      },
      sponsorImage: {
        $ifNull: [
          "$sponsorImage",
          "https://livwell.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/web/download.jpeg"
        ]
      },
      isLinkAvailable: "$isLinkAvailable",
      discountPercent: "$discountPercent",
      hasExternalLink: "$hasExternalLink",
      buyerCount: "$totalUsers",
      buyerTextColor: "#FFFFFF",
      buyerBackgroundColorCode: "#00FF00",
      validityColorCode: {
        $ifNull: [
          "$validityColorCode",
          "#FDFDFD"
        ]
      },
      validityBackgroundColorCode: {
        $ifNull: [
          "$validityBackgroundColorCode",
          "#FF0000"
        ]
      },
      // isDealsOfTheDay: "$isDealsOfTheDay",
      // isFeatured: "$isFeatured",
      hasExternalLinkWithCode: "$hasExternalLinkWithCode",
      hasScanner: "$hasScanner",
      corporateId: "$corporateId"
    }
  },
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": null,
      "sortBy": {
        buyerCount: -1
      },
      "output": {
        "mostPurchasedRank": {
          $rank: {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": null,
      "sortBy": {
        created: -1
      },
      "output": {
        "latestRewardsRank": {
          $rank: {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "grouping": {
        "$switch": {
          "branches": [
            {
              "case": {
                $lte: [
                  "$mostPurchasedRank",
                  2// your per group limit here
                  
                ]
              },
              "then": "mostPurchased"
            },
            {
              "case": {
                $lte: [
                  "$latestRewardsRank",
                  2// your per group limit here
                  
                ]
              },
              "then": "latestRewards"
            },
            {
              "case": {
                $lt: [
                  "$points",
                  300
                ]
              },
              "then": "suggestedRewards"
            }
          ],
          default: null
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": "$grouping",
      "sortBy": {
        "_id": 1
      },
      "output": {
        "inGroupRanking": {
          $rank: {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      inGroupRanking: {
        $lte: 2// your per group limit here
        
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$grouping",
      "docs": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

sorry for late check , I'm using v4.2.14 and throwing error like Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$setWindowFields. Does it really works from v5.0?

@ram12393 yes, $setWindowFields is introduced from v5.0. TBH, v4.2 is really old and you should consider upgrading the database version if possible.

Use $group to aggregate unique documents based on a unique identifier.
Apply the $facet stage to perform the required operations for each array.
[
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      doc: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$doc"
    }
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      mostPurchased: [
        {
          $sort: {
            buyerCount: -1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 15
        }
      ],
      latestRewards: [
        {
          $sort: {
            created: -1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 15
        }
      ],
      suggestedRewards: [
        {
          $match: {
            points: {
              $lt: 300
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 15
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      mostPurchased: 1,
      latestRewards: 1,
      suggestedRewards: 1
    }
  }
]


Your solution is incorrect; in the sense that a single document can still appear in 2 groups.
